# Existence of an idempotent element in a finite monoid.

Tags: group-theory, monoid, associativity

I'm trying to show that if $E$ is a finite monoid, then there exists $s$ such that $s²=s$, i.e, there exists an idempotent element in $E$.

What I did is this:
Take an element $a$ of $E$, and consider the application $F_a :E\to E$ such that for $x$ in $E$, $F_a(x)=ax$.
Now, if $E$ was a group, it's easy to see that $F_a$ is a permutation of $E$ (consider $F_{sym}(a)$)  since $E$ is finite.
Then there exists at least one element $x$ such that $F_a(x)=x$.
Take $x=a$ we'll have $a²=a$. 
But what about the initial case, where $E$ is just a finite monoid?

Thanks.

Comment: Monoids have identity elements, so you can take $s$ to be the identity element of $E$.

Comment: I just reread the definition of a monoid, never paid attention to the presence of an identity element ! Thank you so much for this simple answer.

Comment: You could replace monoid by semigroup in the question. Then Hagen von Eitzen's answer applies.

Answer (score 5):

The sequence $a,a^2,a^3,a^4,\ldots$
is *eventually* periodic, i.e., there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ and $p>0$ suvch that $a^{n+p}=a^n$ for all $n>N$. This is weaker than what we have for groups (immediate periodicity), but it suffices to find idempotent $s$. For example $s=a^m$ for $m$ a multiple of $p$ that is $>N$.

Comment: Thank You so much for this concise answer !